# Run a function only at first callback, but more elegantly way

Tags: javascript, callback

I would like to get always the "true" result, but in a more elegant way. Is this possible?

```
function callB(cb) {
  var i = 1;
  while (i <= 5) {
    cb(i);
    i++;
  }
}

var i = 0;
callB(function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  if (i === 0) {
    console.log(true);
    i++;
  }
});
```

I want the result is always after the first callback, but that after, the callb function does not continue to generate more callbacks

Comment: Can you explain what exactly you want?

Comment: Do you want to do this without modifying the `callB()` function? I.e., by changing only the function you pass to it as a callback?

Comment: What do you mean by always "true"? Care to elaborate more?

Answer (score 2):

You could wrap the whole part in a function which is called before.

This function keeps track if it is the first call and prevent more calls of the callback.

```js
function once(fn) {
    var run = true;
    return function() {
        console.log(arguments); // omit later
        if (run) {
            fn.apply(null, arguments);
            run = false;
        }
    }
}

function callB(cb) {
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= 5) {
        cb(i);
        i++;
    }
}

callB(once(function (value) {
     console.log(value, true);
}));
```

Comment: Does it save RAM memory by doing so? because doing like I did, I had computer freeze, in large functions

Comment: it does not save ram. it is just a different writing of the functionality.

Comment: Ok. Do you think that I could put a timeout if the callback doesn't arrive within 10 seconds?

Comment: just try it. maybe you need another variable for it.

Comment: do i use a setTimeout at 10 seconds that does fn.apply(null, arguments); and run = false;?

Comment: it depends on the need. try it and see what happen.

Comment: I need a timeout of 10 seconds in the "once" function, if no callbacks are coming, and that it blocks the eventual next callbacks

Answer (score 1):

As you run this once and your concern is performance then don't put your callback inside loop.

```js
function callB(cb) {
  var i = 1;
  cb(i);
  while (i <= 5) {
    i++;
  }
}
callB( v => console.log('Runs once with value ' + v));
```

Answer (score -1):

I adjusted the function depending on my needs, thus:

```
function once(fn) {

    var run = true;

    var timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        if (run) {
            fn(false);
            run = false;
        }
    }, 5000);

    return function () {
        console.log(arguments); // omit later
        if (run) {
            fn.apply(null, arguments);
            //resolve(true);
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            run = false;
        }
    };

}

function callB(cBa) {
    var i = 1;
    while (i <= 5) {
        //cBa(i);
        i++;
    }
}

callB(once(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
}));
```

Comment: it does not work this way: *Thank you all*. you may have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers